# Kubernetes - Best Practices for Physical Network Segmentation

Tags: networking, dmz, kubernetes, zones, master

Based on the following design constraint, does anyone have any best practices or recommendations regarding how to deploy Kubernetes across multiple network zones?

What is the most common and accepted method to this approach?

For example if I have a typical DMZ, App Zone, Data Zone, I want my nginx containers to run in the DMZ, my node.js app container in the App Zone and my MongoDB container in the Data Zone.

Or

At greater cost I can deploy a kubernetes cluster per zone with each zone having it's own master and worker nodes - although this seems like a significant investment when also having to factor in disaster recovery or a site active/active requirement.

Would I deploy K8s masters in the DMZ along with the worker Nodes in the DMZ and remaining App and DB Zones?

I understand that I could deploy everything to the App Zone and use SDN to create the same network zoning and load balance my requests from the DMZ into the cluster, but that is not what I want to do.

Much Appreciated.

Tommy B.